# How to make custom useTabDoublePressEffect() in React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How can I call a callback function when I press on a tab in Tab.Navigator which is already selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The custom useTabDoublePressEffect hook:

```
import {EventArg, useNavigation, useRoute} from '@react-navigation/native';
import React from 'react';

export default function useTabDoublePressEffect(callback: Function) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const route = useRoute();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let current = navigation; // The screen might be inside another navigator such as stack nested in tabs

    // We need to find the closest tab navigator and add the listener there
    while (current && current.getState().type !== 'tab') {
      current = current.getParent();
    }

    if (!current) {
      return;
    }

    const unsubscribe = current.addListener(
      // We don't wanna import tab types here to avoid extra deps
      // in addition, there are multiple tab implementations
      //   @ts-expect-error
      'tabPress',

      (e: EventArg<'tabPress', true>) => {
        // We should scroll to top only when the screen is focused
        const isFocused = navigation.isFocused(); // In a nested stack navigator, tab press resets the stack to first screen
        // So we should scroll to top only when we are on first screen

        const isFirst =
          navigation === current ||
          navigation.getState().routes[0].key === route.key;

        // Run the operation in the next frame so we're sure all listeners have been run
        // This is necessary to know if preventDefault() has been called

        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          if (isFocused && isFirst && !e.defaultPrevented) {
            callback();
          }
        });
      },
    );
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation, route.key]);
}
```

#### Basic example for how to use it:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import useTabDoublePressEffect from '../hooks/useTabDoublePressEffect';

export default function SomeComponent() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('Hello');

  useTabDoublePressEffect(() => setText('Bye'));

  return <Text>{text}</Text>;
}
```

#### Code borrowed from:

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/ac24e617af10c48b161d1aaa7dfc8c1c1218a3cd/packages/native/src/useScrollToTop.tsx